# MVC Passing List to View Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list in the controller as follows:

```
    public class TruckData
    {
       public string Truck{ get; set; }                        
    }


     var truckdat = (from p in KowaDataContext.tblTrucks
                     orderby p.Truck
                     select new TruckData {Truck= p.Truck});


     var trucklist = truckdat.ToList();

     ViewBag.TrckList= trucklist;
```

The View looks like the following:

```
    @foreach (Data.Rep.Controllers.TruckController.TruvckData item in ViewBag.TrckList)         
    {
     <tr>        

      <td>
         @item.Truck
      </td>
   </tr>      

   }
```

My question is, how can I pass the list to the view without using the class:

```
     public class TruckData
    {
         public string Truck{ get; set; }                        
    }
```

so that my list looks like the following: Notice how the reference to TruckData is gone below:

```
    var truckdat = (from p in KowaDataContext.tblTrucks
                       orderby p.Truck
                       select new {Truck= p.Truck});

     var trucklist = truckdat.ToList();

     ViewBag.TrckList= trucklist;
```

I am not sure how the foreach in the view will look like. I tried what is shown below but was giving me a problem.

```
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TrucksSelectList)
```

Comment: _What error do you get_?

Comment: "... but was giving me a problem." Can you be more explicit about the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You cannot pass anonymous objects to views. The reason for this is that anonymous objects are emitted as **internal** by the compiler. And since ASP.NET dynamically compiles views into a separate assembly they do not have access to this model.

> My question is, how can I pass the list to the view without using the class:

That would be against all good practices => you need to use a view model:

```
var truckdat = 
  from p in KowaDataContext.tblTrucks
  orderby p.Truck
  select new TruckData { Truck = p.Truck };

ViewBag.TrckList = truckdat.ToList();
```

and then in the view:

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<TruckData>)ViewBag.TrckList) 
{
    <div>@item.Truck</div>
}
```

And since you have a list of strings you could probably use that as model:

```
var truckdat = 
  from p in KowaDataContext.tblTrucks
  orderby p.Truck
  select p.Truck;

ViewBag.TrckList = truckdat.ToList();
```

and then in the view:

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.TrckList) 
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

I would also very strongly recommend you to get rid of ViewBag and use strongly typed view models:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<TruckData> model = 
        from p in KowaDataContext.tblTrucks
        orderby p.Truck
        select new TruckData { Truck = p.Truck };

    return View(model);
}
```

and then:

```
@model IEnumerable<TruckData>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@item.Truck</div>
}
```

And introducing a display template for the TruckData type (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/TruckData.cshtml`):

```
@model TruckData
<div>@Model</div>
```

you can even get rid of the ugly and useless foreach loop in your main view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TruckData>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Comment: I did it with the way you mentioned but got the following error: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Truck' and no extension method 'Drug' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) - I tried it this way: @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.TrckList)  {     <div>@item</div> }

Comment: @NatePet, sorry, I did a mistake in my post. I have updated it now. It should be `@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<TruckData>)ViewBag.TrckList) { <div>@item.Truck</div> }`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It cannot find TruckData. I get the following error:  The type or namespace name 'TruckData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I am sure but does it need a path to the TruckData class. If so, as I am using this as a shared view, I may have a problem.

Comment: @NatePet, at the top of your razor view add the namespace where this class is declared: `@using AppName.Models`. And to avoid adding this using directive on each view that requires to access the TruckData class you could also add the namespace to the `<namespaces>` section of `~/Views/web.config` (not `~/web.config`).

Comment: sorry can you elaborate. The complete path to the class in my case is something like: Data.Rep.Controllers.TruckController.TruvckData but keep in mind this is a shared view.

Comment: @NatePet, it seems that the `TruckData` class is defined inside the `TruckController` class? I would recommend you externalizing it in a separate file in `Models\TruckData.cs`. Then add `@using Data.Rep.Models`.